# Mass Edit, but not all locations (grep? sed? awk? vim?)

Tags: editor, grep

I have a relatively big code base that wants a similar change made all over the code.

I have a bunch of lines like this

```
$options = new Options();
```

I want to replace them with

```
$options = Options::getInstance();
```

but in some places I have

```
$options = new Options('alternate_options_file.txt')
```

Those, I want to leave alone.

Further, I expect there to be more changes like this in the future.

I want some way to make this change across the code base without touching every file by hand. In this case, I can easily craft a regular expression to only catch the ones I want. But there are bound to be more complex versions of this coming up. I'd like a general solution that will allow me to:

1. Find a set of possible locations to change
2. Include or Exclude some of them
3. Make the change automatically in the places I've specified.

(I remember using resharper, which would show you a list of all the places it was going to change, and let you include/exclude them. But now I'm working on PHP, and I'd like to make some substitutions other than pure refactorings.)

Right now, my best bet seems to be to use `ack` from inside vim, record a macro, and then use `:cnext` and apply the macro if appropriate. There's probably a better choice though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.ibrahim-ahmed.com/2008/01/find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in.html

Vim can replace text interactively across files, like:

```
:args **/*.php
:argdo %s/new Options()/Options::getInstance()/gec | update
```

I also suggest you commit your whole code base before try this.
Take care not to screw up your repository.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know about args/argdo. That looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: To speed things up, I am now running `ack -l 'new\s*Options()' | xargs mvim`, which gives me a new window with the args set to just the files that contain the target string.

Answer (score 0):

The sed pattern would be

```
s/\$options = new Options();/\$options = Options::getInstance();/g
```

To apply it in-place run with `sed -i` on Linux, or `sed -i.bak` on BSD/Macs then remove the backups). To limit yourself to PHP files, and possibly to only touch the ones with the line, try this:

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs grep -l "\$options = new Options();" | xargs sed -i 's/\$options = new Options();/\$options = Options::getInstance();/g'
```

If you have spaces etc in filenames, try `find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 sed ...`.

Be sure to back up everything first. If you're using source control (right?) and everything's committed before making the change, you should be ok.

Comment: Hmm... but that requires you to craft a regex that includes or excludes exactly the targets you want. I'd like an answer that lets you pick some interactively.